# Arangodb - gremling 2.6 :: missing vertex from gremling interface

Tags: gremlin, arangodb

I can not locate a vertex from within gremlin, which I can retrieve in the web GUI:

From the GUI I filter as:
freebaseid == 68545795554948

From gremlin I query (searching by attribute wo/key) as:
`g.V.has('freebaseid', 68545795554948).next().id`

Raised exception:
`javax.script.ScriptException: com.tinkerpop.pipes.util.FastNoSuchElementException`

Full stack trace: http://pastebin.com/61iPnkBW

Relevant points:

`` 13:32:19.129 [main] DEBUG com.arangodb.http.HttpManager - [REQ]http-POST: url=http://arango:8529/_api/cursor, headers=null, body={"count":false,"batchSize":20,"options":{},"query":"for i in GRAPH_VERTICES(@graphName , @vertexExample, @options) FILTER i.`freebaseid` \u00
3d\u003d @property0 return i","bindVars":{"property0":68545795554948,"vertexExample":{},"graphName":"mysuperdb","options":{"direction":"any","includeData":true}}} ``

`com.arangodb.blueprints.client.ArangoDBException: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to  respond
--- cut ---
Caused by: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond`

Could someone please help me figuring out what's happening here?

**Versions:**
 - ArangoDB: 2.7.7
 - Gremlin: 2.6.0
 - blueprints-arangodb-graph: 1.0.14

Issue on github: https://github.com/arangodb/blueprints-arangodb-graph/issues/25

Answer (score 4):

The ArangoDB client has lost the connection to the server (the server closes inactive connections after 300 seconds)

To avoid this you can increase the "keep-alive-timeout" of the server by:

```
--server.keep-alive-timeout <big number>
```

I changed the behavior of the java client in blueprints-arangodb-graph version 1.0.15. Please update to this version.